# Meteor.call callback is not executed and it's silently ignored if I don't do a fetch

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-methods

Why if I write this:

`/client/Items.js`

```
Template.Items.onCreated(function() {
  console.log('Methor.call');
  Meteor.call('Items.findAll', function (err, resp) {
    console.log('Methor.call callback');
    // Here I will use resp expecting it contains the response
    // returned by the method
    // ...
    return;
  });
  return;
});
```

`/ItemsMethods.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
  'Items.findAll': function () {
    return Items.find({});
  }
});
```

the callback is silently ignored, i.e. it is not executed and I don't get any error?

Note that if I replace this `return Items.find({});` with this `return Items.find({}).fetch();` all works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are returning a cursor in a [Meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods), the callback will not be called, because cursors are not serialisable. As the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) states, Meteor methods should return an [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson)-able value or throw an exception.

There is actually a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5382), which describes this issue in more detail.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. I hope in the future will be thrown an exception (at least server side) for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

`Items.find({});` return a cursor that is a sort of pointer to the data retrieved.

If you use `Items.find({}).fetch();` you are returning an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks for clarify this. I still do not understand why in the first case the `Meteor.call`'s callback is not executed? Is it related with the type of data the method return?